# add other servers permanently to cockpit (dashboard)

Tags: arch-linux, webserver, cockpit

Im using cockpit https://cockpit-project.org/ to have a web interface on my servers and local smaller machines. Im able to add a other system just fine by filling in the required ip (custom ssh port) and username. Clicking works fine and im in the other host now fine.

But when i logout or access the same first host from another ip(interface its connected to) the other hosts list is empty. And even when i login again from the former ip, all other hosts are gone. As if its a session only feature.

How can i make this switching to other hosts permanently? Im using arch hosts for now, do i need an extra config or package maybe to make the addition permanent?

Answer (score 0):

This feels silly, but I waited a couple of hours. rebooted and now it seems to remember the other hosts. and even if I access from the other IP, the other hosts are still accessible.